# Stuck in vim because of try command

Tags: vim

As the title states, I cannot exit vim due to accidentally typing `:try`  command. I all the ways I have tried resulted in the typed text showing up as a command.
Is there a way to exit or am I such here for good?

Edit:
[image: Picture of the problem]

Comment: can't you just type `:q`, `:q!`, or `q` to get out?

Comment: ctrl-c ? 7 more to go...

Comment: No. I am in command mode but under `:try`. Any thing that gets typed shows up as a command under `:try`

Comment: You could also do `ctrl + z` to stop vim, go back to terminal, and kill the process.

Comment: Andy Ray thanks that solved it

Comment: Try `:qa!` and tell us.

Comment: By the way, try accepts commands, not commands prefixed by colon. Colon is a character used to go _into_ command _mode_. You're in try _mode_ and you could also type `q` in try mode and it will run the q command and exit Vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get out of `try` mode, and many Vim modes (including insert mode) with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>. See `:h ctrl-c` for more.

Additionally, try accepts commands, not commands prefixed by colon. Colon is a character used to go into command mode. You're in try mode and you could also type q in try mode and it will run the q command and exit Vim.

You can also kill Vim by it's process id using `kill` from a different terminal.

Comment: 1. There is no such thing as "`try` mode". 2. it's *command-line mode*, not "command mode".